# Linearity of a function in Mathematica

Tags: functions, function-construction, linear-algebra, symbolic, operators

I have a function which has something like

`myFunc[q,a state[c,d]]`

`a` could be anything, and I want to tell *Mathematica* that this part of the function is linear, so that the coefficient of `state[c,d]` can be taken outside so that it achieves this result

`a myFunc[q,state[c,d]]`

Can this be done?

Why is this important? I'm doing simulations on quantum mechanics, and operators have to be linear with respect to numbers, and this is important to make calculations easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

> ```
> myFunc[q_, f_ + g_] := myFunc[q, f] + myFunc[q, g]
> myFunc[q_, a_ f_state] := a myFunc[q, f] /; FreeQ[a, state]
> ```

So that

```
myFunc[q, a state[c, d]]
```

> ```
>    a myFunc[q, state[c,d] ]
> ```

and

```
myFunc[q, a state[c, d] + b  state[e, h]]
```

> ```
>    a myFunc[q, state[c, d]] + b myFunc[q, state[e, h]]
> ```

You can still assign a specific definition to `myFunc[q_, f_state]`.

Comment: You are `Flatten`ing me. ---   No, wait...